# Import Wallet.dat with bitcoins on it

Tags: wallet.dat

This might sound a bit odd. I have had a Bitcoin app for a few years now. A few years ago I made a copy of Wallet.dat and put it on a stick. Now my computer crashed and i don't know how to import it or where to put it. I got Bitcoin Core and let it install and download the blockchain completely. I was thinking that after the process finishes I will see a folder with a Wallet.dat in it and replace it with my own. However,it has no wallet.dat in it and i don't know how to import my own. What should I do? Did I get a wrong version?

[image: here is how it looks like. I have looked for a wallet.dat in it but it doesnt have any]

Comment: I don't have windows, but I think you are in the wrong directory.

Comment: Check %APPDATA%\Bitcoin (This defaults to C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin on Windows XP and to C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin on Windows Vista, 7, and 8.) and change wallet.dat file with yours